# Azure ServiceBus Topics and Queues

Tags: azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

Good afternoon guys, I'm going through an interesting situation.

I have a topic and this topic has two queues, and in my source code, I'm going to send a message to the topic. But the problem is that in one of the queues, the message should be read only after 24 hours.

Is there any configuration to do in the queue or some property to put in the BrokeredMessage that I am sending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could publish/send your messages scheduled for future delivery specifying [`ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.scheduledenqueuetimeutc?view=azure-dotnet) value.

**Update**: you could leverage a [Filter Rule Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters#actions) on subscription to set the `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` value.

**Update 2**: The idea with filter rule action won't work. Evaluation is done on the topic (which is a queue on its own) and not on subscription. Not to mention the documentation that has almost no details on how to do it.

Alternative approach could be to set a default TTL on your subscription and enable "Deal Lettering On Message Expiration". That will move any messages with the expired TTL of 24 hours (or any other arbitary time you need) to the subscription's dead-letter queue. With that in place, you can set up "Forward Dead Lettered Messages To" to a queue your endpoint needs to process.

Comment: But I need to schedule message only for one of the two subscriptions, for the other i wanna send immediately

Comment: Then you can't do it. Publishing messages means any subscriber will get it. Unless you introduce something specific to the queue listener to defer a message once it's received from a subscription, not much you could do.

Comment: Now thinking about it, rule action could be an option. Updated my answer.

Comment: hmmmm I understand, and how does it work? all the messages that go to the signature will be scheduled? Can I configure that rule action using the Azure's portal or only by code?

Comment: Code or tools. Cogin's QueueExplorer can do it. ServiceBusExplorer can only visualize for now.

Comment: hmm okay, I got it, for now I think I gonna use a web job because I don't have much time, but I gonna study later about your answer, thx guy!

Comment: You gave me an idea for a blog post, so thank you. It will be on https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman

Comment: That's nice guy, I'm glad for give you the idea! I'll save the link and follow up for when the post comes out.

Comment: @MiguelPatreze after digging a little into Actions, this is not an approach that would be supported. I've updated the answer with another option. If you feel it's not what you need, feel free to unmark my post as a valid answer. I'm still going to dig more into actions to find out _what_ is actaully possible.